# How to 'Access to an object javascript'

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to the data in ['messages-id'] and messages => to (object) but i am unable get undefined.

```
info: response ended: 200 {
    'message-count': '1',
    messages: [{
        to: '1325001221',
        'message-id': '1400000034AE4F63',
        status: '0',
        'remaining-balance': '1.88032000',
        'message-price': '0.01088000',
        network: '302320'
    }]
}
```

I'm trying to use socket.io to get a responseData and send it to from server side to client side. but the problem is that, i am unable to get the data in

```
const data = {
  id: responseData.messages[0]['message-id']
  to: responseData.messages[0].to
}

console.log('Pulled Data', data.id)

//Emit to client
io.emit('smsStatus', data);
```

I expect to get the value of the following:

```
messages: [{
      to: '1325001221',
      'message-id': '1400000034AE4F63',
```

Comment: Is the `id: responseData.messages[0].to` what you meant? You sure it's not a typo? And you are also missing some commas in data structure

Comment: console.log(responseData) and check whether it has object you wish to retrieve

Answer (score -1):

You may try out as,

```js
let obj = {
    'message-count': '1',
    messages: [{
        to: '1325001221',
        'message-id': '1400000034AE4F63',
        status: '0',
        'remaining-balance': '1.88032000',
        'message-price': '0.01088000',
        network: '302320'
    }]
};

let msg1 = obj.messages[0];

console.log(msg1['to']);
console.log(msg1['message-id']);
console.log(msg1['status']);
console.log(msg1['remaining-balance']);
console.log(msg1['message-price']);
console.log(msg1['network']);
```

This is called as Object literal syntax.

Please refer to,   http://javascript.info/object-basics

Comment: What i am experiencing is that, 'messages' is inside a bigger object and i am trying to figure how to access that bigger object. 
take a look at this code below:

info: response ended: 200
{ 'message-count': '1',
  messages:
   [ { to: '13653383391',
       'message-id': '1500000032F62D25',
       status: '0',
       'remaining-balance': '1.86944000',
       'message-price': '0.01088000',
       network: '302320' } ] }